# Use SemanticImport on column with UnixTime in miliseconds

Tags: functions, import, date-and-time

When I use [`SemanticImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) on a csv file with the following data I get a [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) with the year value in the 40 thousands, e.g.

```
DateObject[{48981, 1, 14}, 
 TimeObject[{14, 54, 58.`}, TimeZone -> 1.`], 
 TimeZone -> 1.`]
```

This is the command I use.

```
SemanticImport["filename.csv", <|"timestamp" -> "UnixTime", "value" -> "Real"|>]
```

I found out that the timestamp is in milleseconds since epoch, but I can't find a way to import this with SemanticImport.

Example Data:

```
timestamp   value
1483525115395   6.2315826416015625
1483525115495   6.2315826416015625
1483525115596   6.2315826416015625
1483525115698   6.2315826416015625
1483525115762   6.56842041015625
1483525115800   6.56842041015625
1483525115860   6.399993896484375
1483525115902   6.399993896484375
1483525116005   6.399993896484375
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about converting them afterwards?

```
SemanticImport[
  "filename.csv", <|"timestamp" -> "Integer", "value" -> "Real"|>
  ][
 All, {"timestamp" -> (FromUnixTime[#/1000] &)}
 ]
```

Comment: When I use DataObject I get the wrong date, it seems to count from 1900 instead 1970. This works for me: `data[All, {"timestamp" -> (Interpreter["UnixTime"][#/1000] &)}]`

Comment: @PeterStuifzand right, will correct that later. There is `FromUnixTime` too.

Comment: I have never used `SemanticImport` before, but due to this answer I played with it and found that it will accept pure functions in the column import specifications directly, so you could directly get the same result with ``"timestamp" -> (FromUnixTime[Internal`StringToDouble@#/1000] &)``. You also seem to have forgotten to also update the ouput...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I think you should post an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

As Kuba and Peter already found out the problem is that the timestamps are in milliseconds instead of seconds which makes necessary a corresponding correction.

Similar to Kuba's answer you can also directly use a `Function` instead of a string in the column specifications for `SemanticImport`, e.g.:

```
SemanticImport[
  "filename.csv", <|
     "timestamp" -> (FromUnixTime[Internal`StringToDouble@#/1000] &), 
     "value" -> "Real"
  |>
]
```

Honestly after consulting the documentation I'm not sure whether I should consider that to be documented or not, it probably is not...

While this also works with `SemanticImportString` in general there are cases which don't work, e.g. the following example fails for me (MMA on Windows 7):

```
str = "timestamp   value
  1483525115395   6.2315826416015625
  1483525115495   6.2315826416015625
  1483525115596   6.2315826416015625
  1483525115698   6.2315826416015625
  1483525115762   6.56842041015625
  1483525115800   6.56842041015625
  1483525115860   6.399993896484375
  1483525115902   6.399993896484375
  1483525116005   6.399993896484375";

SemanticImportString[str, <|
  "timestamp" -> (FromUnixTime[Internal`StringToDouble@#/1000] &), 
  "value" -> Internal`StringToDouble|>]
```

on the other hand this (and some other similar cases) works as expected:

```
SemanticImportString[str, <|
  "timestamp" -> (FromUnixTime[Internal`StringToDouble@#/1000] &), 
  "value" -> "Real"|>]
```